# Two parameterized curves?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

Problem 2. Consider the two parametrized curves
$$r_1(t) = \langle 1 + t^2, 2 − t, t^4 + 3t^2 − 4t + 4 \rangle$$
$$r_2(u) = \langle u^2, 3 − u, u^4 + u^2 − 6u + 8 \rangle$$
where $t,u \in \mathbb{R}$.

(a) Find the coordinates of the point of intersection $P$ of the two curves.
(b) The curves traced out by $r_1$ and $r_2$ lie on a surface $S$. Find an equation of the tangent plane to the
surface $S$ at the point $P$ found in part (a).

a) For a I just set up a system of two equations $1 + t^2 = u^2$ and
$2 - t = 3 - u$. I solved for $U$ and $T$ and was able to obtain the point by subsequently plugging in values of $t$ and $u$ and got the point of interesection as (1,2,4). My new problem is b. I have no ideas on how to approach b. Please let me know however if my approach to part a is wrong. Thank you.

Comment: The idea for (b) is this: If $T$ is the tangent plane at $P$, and since the curve $r_1(t)$ lies on $S$, the tangent line of $r_1(t)$ at the point $P$ will lie inside the tangent plane $T$. So if you compute the tangent line of $r_1(t)$ at the point $P$, you get a vector that lies inside tangent plane $T$. By the same reasoning, you can compute tangent line of $r_2(u)$ and get another vector lying inside $T$. These two vectors (if they are not pointing in the same direction) will determine $T$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two vectors that lie in that tangent plane to $S$ at $P$ are the derivatives of the two curves at $P$, where $t=0$ and $u=1$:
$$r_1'(t)=(2t, -1,4t^3+6t-4)\implies r_1'(0)=(0,-1,-4)$$
$$r_2'(u)=(2u,-1,4u^3+2u-6)\implies r_2'(1)=(2,-1,0)$$
The cross product of these two vectors gives the normal as $(-4,-8,2)$, which we scale to $(2,4,-1)$. This dotted with $(1,2,4)$ yields $6$, so the equation of the plane is $(2,4,-1)\cdot\mathbf r=2x+4y-z=6$.

Your part (a) is right.